# What is multi line pattern in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want match multi line

```
/add val1::val2
```

and work via this pattern

```
^/add +(.+)::+(.+)$
```

but not work in multi line
for example:

```
/add line1
line2
::
linexx
lineYY
```

tested this pattern but not work

```
^/add ([%w%s]*)::([%w%s]*)
```

Comment: Should use the multi-line mode using `s` flag

Comment: my text is : `/add line1
    line2
    ::
    linexx
    lineYY` i want pattern for this text
first pattern only work for one line, not work for multiline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` matches any character, including `\n`. Since you don't want to match multi-line strings, exclude `\n` explicitly, i.e, use `[^\n]` to replace `.`:

```
^/add +([^\n]+)::+([^\n]+)$
```

Test:

```
local str1 = '/add val1::val2'
local str2 = [[/add line1
line2
::
linexx
lineYY]]

local pattern = '^/add +([^\n]+)::+([^\n]+)$'

print(str1:match(pattern))
print(str2:match(pattern))
```

Comment: i used this `^/add +([^.]+)::+([^.]+)$` and worked, but if in text have dot character not work, for example: `/add line1
line2.
::
linexx
lineYY` after line2 have dot (.) and not work, why?

Comment: Because within the brackets the `.` is interpreted as `%.`, so `[^.]` means anything that is not a period. You want to use `[^\n]` like @Yu Hao said